# where should i start before using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hai guys,
       As i want to develop an application using asp.net MVC, i dont know where should i start...
I ve done some applications using asp.net webforms and now i want to make a move to asp.net mvc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the complete Nerd Dinner tutorial from start to finish. You can find it [here](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The "What is ASP.NET MVC?" page on the ASP.NET site is probably one of the best places to start:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/whatisaspmvc/

I would highly suggest watching the video.

From there, I'd also suggest [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/), in particular, his post titled "ASP.NET MVC Framework":

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

He also has a number of other posts on the ASP.NET MVC framework, which are generally tagged with "MVC":

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx

Of course, Google will turn up a number of sources, and there is always the vast array of information here.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you watch these videos: [ASP.NET MVC Storefront Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/#MVCStorefrontStarterKit) and read some [books](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/10/14/ChoosingAnMvcBook.aspx)